# Basic question about the joint probability.

Tags: probability-theory

I have a doubt regarding the joint probability.

Experiment:

I have a deck of cards marked from $1$ to $4$. Two cards are drawn in sequence *without replacement*. Let $X$ denote the random variable corresponding to the value obtained from the first card. Let $Y$ denote the random variable corresponding to the value obtained from the second card. If the probability of drawing the first card marked $1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, then the probability of drawing the second card marked $1$ is $0$. I did not understand this point.

How can it be certain that first card drawn is $1$ to make the probability of drawing the second card marked $1$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > If the probability of drawing the first card marked 1 is $1/4$, then the probability of drawing the second card marked 1 is 0.
>
> I did not understand this point.
>
> How can it be certain that first card drawn is 1 to make the probability of drawing the second card marked 1 is 0.

It can't be certain, but sometimes it does happen, and *whenever it does*, then what would you say would be the probability that the second card is also that same card?

---

They are talking *conditional* probability.   When *given* that the first card is `1` the second card cannot be.   There can only be one (when drawing without replacement from a deck of 4 cards).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=1) & =\tfrac 1 4\\[1ex]\mathsf P(Y=1\mid X=1) & =0\end{align}$$

Likewise when *given* that the first card is *not* a `1` the *conditional* probability that the second card is `1`, is:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\neq 1)& =\tfrac 3 4\\[1ex]\mathsf P(Y=1\mid X\neq 1) & =\tfrac 1 3\end{align}$$

Then the *marginal* probability that the second card is `1` is (from the *Law of Total Probability*) given by:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=1) & = \mathsf P(Y=1\mid X=1)~\mathsf P(X=1)+\mathsf P(Y=1\mid X\neq 1)~\mathsf P(X\neq 1) \\[1ex] & = 0+\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 3 4 \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 4\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think what they mean is if the first card is a $1$ then the probability of the second card is $0$ since that card has already been drawn.  This is a conditional probability.  But it doesn't make sense to say if "the probability" the first is $1$ "is $1/4$" then the probability the second is a $1$ is $0$.  You have to remove the parts in quotes for it to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am understanding this, when it says "I have a deck of cards marked from $1$ to $4$" they actually mean they only have one of each card in the deck (i.e. a deck of four cards), as such, if a card has been drawn in the first draw, it can not be drawn in the second.